# Simulate the connect and disconnect of the charging cable on the Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can I simulate the connection and the disconnection of the charging cable on the Android emulator?

Comment: Am also having the same problem given the fact that when one is debugging you can not disconnect the cable. This means you can not debug the action

Comment: did you find at least a way to disconnect it?

Comment: sorry had not seen you are using emulator

Answer (score 10):

With the new emulator introduced in Android Studio 2.0 you can switch connection status easily on emulator extended controls.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#power

On command line call:

```
telnet localhost 5554
```

and then:

```
  power ac off
  power ac on
```