# How to make a Charging Battery Simulator (Android)?

Tags: android, telnet, simulator, battery

I am using a Android Simulator called NoxPlayer. I want it to be on a battery charging mode ,as if I have a real cell phone connected to a USB charger.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888848/simulate-the-connect-and-disconnect-of-the-charging-cable-on-the-android-emulato) can help. I'm not sure if that applies to NoxPlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set that up in emulator properties. Press three dots next to your emulator -> Battery -> Battery Charging

[image]

Comment: do you know any emulator that has this battery option?

Comment: Every emulator works pretty much the same way, if you want to access battery options you have to access them as I described you

Comment: You know how i can put emulator properties in a Android Emulator like MEmu ??